# Enum: Switch case for variables of type

Tags: swift, enums

How come when I try to unwrap and optional which has the enum friendstate do I get an error when I try to apply it in the switch statement below? The error provied is

Enum case "added" not found in type "friendState!"

(error replicates for all cases)

Is there a way to fix this error?

```
var usernameText : String!
var UID : Int!
var userDetails : UserState?
var buttonText : String{
    switch(userDetails!.state){
    case .added:
        return "remove"//error occurs
    case .incoming:
        return "accept"//error occurs
    case .outgoing:
        return "cancel"//error occurs
    }

}

func setup(){
    ActButton.setTitle(buttonText, forState: .Normal)
}


enum friendState : Int,Printable{

case incoming,added,outgoing

var description : String{
    switch(self){
    case .incoming:
        return "incoming"
    case .added:
        return "Friends"
    case .outgoing:
        return "outgoing"
    }
  }
}


class UserState : Printable , Hashable{
var uid : Int!
var username : String
var isFollowing : Bool
var state : friendState!
var RequestForUser : Request?

init( username : String, isFollowing : Bool, state : friendState, uid :Int){
    self.username = username
    self.isFollowing = isFollowing
    self.state = state
    self.uid = uid
}

var hashValue : Int {
    get{
        return uid
    }
}

var description : String{
    return "UserName: \(username) Following : \(isFollowing) Association: \(state) \n"
}
```

}

Comment: Where is UserState defined?

Comment: Just added Userstate definition. It is defined as its own class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `var buttonText : String`

Just change the line:

```
switch(userDetails!.state)
```

with

```
switch(userDetails!.state!)
```

You need to unwrap userDetails optional state.

Comment: ! implies optional too? also Thank you

Comment: You can either add the '!' in the switch or just declare state as 'var state : friendState' without '!'. If you marked it unwrapped then you need to mark it explicitly when you reference it.